# Почему не работает ни mail() ни wp_mail()?

Tags: php, email

HTML

```
            <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h2 style="text-align:center">Заказать звонок</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" id="form" class="form-search">
                        <input id="phone" name="phone" required="required" placeholder="введите номер" type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Заказать</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $('#modal').click(function(){
         $('#modal').modal();
     });
    $("#form").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Метод отправки
            url: "wp-content/themes/realhomes/send.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {
                //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!"+form_data);
            }
        })
    });
        });
```

php

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
    $to = 'lunatikspb@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
    $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
    $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
    $headers .= "From: Отправитель <lunatikspb@gmail.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
    $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/attach.zip');
    $headers = 'From: My Name <lunatikspb@seosky.com>' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail('diablospb@yandex.ru','Сделать новый звонок',$_POST['phone'],$headers,$attachments);
    if(mail==true){
        echo "<script>alert(' wp_mail victory');</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('wp_mail fail');</script>";
    }
if(wp_mail==true){
    echo "<script>alert(' wp_mail victory');</script>";
}
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('wp_mail fail');</script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте настройки почтовика. Обычно проблема именно в них.

Comment: Где проверить какие?

Comment: На хостинге. Чаще всего юзается smtp. Возможно хостер и не поддерживает данный функционал. Обратитесь в техпод хостинга лучше...

Comment: Перенесите в клиенты плиз если можите

Comment: Скрипты ошибки выдают, или пишут что все ок?